# How to unhide application crash reports in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, apport

I had lxappearance crash a few times when trying to install icon themes as described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxappearance/+bug/952997

The first few times there was crash report i could read, then it stopped appearing i think because the crash report window had pre checked the option to not display future reports from this app. How do I change that preference back to being able to see the reports?

Comment: You can view /var/log/apport.log to see a log of crash reports and that might help.